# Angular ng-pattern with input 'type=email' to validate ASCII characters

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, validation, email

I am trying to validate emails such as the following `IE11invité@test.com` and `üñîçøðé@example.com` in a sign up form with AngularJS.

The problem here is that the current validation only works for the following types of emails `something@somwhere` `something@somewhere.com` and does not validate for ASCII characters like I am trying to validate.

Current HTML:

```
 <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailInput" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="255" maxlength="255" required>
```

I have a REGEX that validates these emails in a REGEX tester but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get the `input` to validate against it and set a couple `ng-show`'s if it valid.

```
$scope.emailValid = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

And my HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="emailInput" ng-model="user.email" ng-patten="emailValid" placeholder="Email" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="255" maxlength="255" required>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" ng-show="registrationForm.emailInput.$invalid && !registrationForm.emailInput.$pristine"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" ng-show="registrationForm.emailInput.$valid && !registrationForm.emailInput.$pristine"></span>
```

The code above validates if there is a min of 3 characters always and I don't think ever checks against my REGEX.

Comment: I think the question title is misleading, isn't this specifically about validating email addresses containing non-ASCII characters?

Comment: You have a typo above, is that typo in your code as well? `ng-patten` should be `ng-pattern`.

Comment: @SunilD. amazing. that was my problem the entire time. THANK YOU!

Comment: I tried your regex, with no other attrs required and still doesn't validate correctly. is there anything else you had to do to get the model to validate with ASCII chars?